# How to run VACUUM in redshift using python?

Tags: sql, python-2.7, amazon-redshift

> Getting error:

```
next(df)
```

TypeError: DataFrame object is not an iterator

Here goes the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import psycopg2
import csv



def redshift():

conn=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'sdsdf', host='rghgj', 
    port= '5439', user= 'admin', password= 'assddfd')
df=pd.read_sql('select table_name from vacuum_process where vacuum_enable=1',conn)
conn.autocommit=True
print df
next(df)

    for i in df:

         curr=conn.cursor()
         query= "vacuum  %s "% i
         curr.execute(query)
         print 'success'

redshift()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to set the `isolation_level=0` in your connection, hence code is begining the transaction and then executing the query.

Though I don't understand full(why to select if need to run vacuum), what you're trying to do here, but I'll not go into that details. Here is simplistic code that should work for `table1`.

```
import psycopg2



def redshift():

    conn=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'a', host='host', port= '5439', user= 'user_name', password= '****')
    conn.set_isolation_level(0)
    cur = conn.cursor();

    cur.execute('vacuum table1')
    print('success')


redshift();
```

**Edit 13/6/2018**

Code to do Vaccum for multiple tables. This could be enhanced to read table names from DB/text files/CSV/property files etc.

```
tables = ["sales", "sales", "tab3", "tab3"];

i = 0

while i < len(tables):
    cur.execute('vacuum ' + tables[i])

    print('success ' + tables[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: To automate the vacuum process ,i am creating this code. yeah now i cleared that error  but getting different error now.

Comment: TypeError: DataFrame object is not an iterator

Comment: OK, if it works, you could accept this answer. If other problem, you may want to ask different question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating correctly over rows in the DataFrame. several good ways to iterate over DataFrame rows can be found in this link:[How to iterate over DataFrame rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)